# In python, using tkinter, my random numbers only generate once?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import string
from tkinter import filedialog

ktwoWin = Tk() #window
qLabel = StringVar()
userAnswer = StringVar()
ktwoWin.withdraw() #hide the ktwoWin window
pass

num1= random.randint(1, 12) #random numbers
num2= random.randint(1, 12)
Answer= num1 * num2

def ktwoOpen():
    ktwoWin.deiconify() #show the ktwoWin window

    ktwoWin.title("Kindergarten to Grade Two")
    ktwoWin.geometry("400x300")
    ktwoWin.grid()

    askbutton= Button(ktwoWin, text="ask me a question!", command = askquestion, height=3, width=16, bg="blue")
    askbutton.grid(column= 0, row= 0)

    submitbtn= Button(ktwoWin, text="Submit Answer", command=checkanswer, height=3, width=12, bg= "red")
    submitbtn.grid(column=1, row=0)

    q=Label(ktwoWin,textvariable=qLabel)
    q.grid(column=1, row=1)
    q.config(text="text to go here")
    qLabel.set("some text")
    answerentry= Entry(ktwoWin, textvariable=userAnswer)
    answerentry.grid(column=3, row=3)
    pass

def askquestion():
    qLabel.set("what is" +str(num1) + "x" + str(num2) + "?")

def checkanswer():
    useranswer=userAnswer.get()
    if int(useranswer) != Answer:
        messagebox.showwarning(message="the answer is " + str(Answer))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="correct!")

ktwoWin.mainloop
```

Which, when I run the program, the random numbers I have, will only randomise once, if that makes sense? My question, ultimately, is there a way for me to loop the random number part of the code?
any help is appreciated, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward to set up a new question each time one is answered. I'm not an expert at tkinter, so this is fairly general advice.

To start with, set up your two random numbers in the `askquestion` function, rather than at the top level of your module. Since you need to be able to access the product later, use the `global` keyword to make sure that the answer is available outside the function's scope (or you could reorganize the code into a class and use member variables).

You may also need to add some extra logic to the end of the `checkanswer` function to reset the program's state after an answer has been provided (e.g. clear the old question label and remove the old answer from the input box). Depending on how you want the program to play, you might immediately ask a new question, or you might go back to the original starting state.